# Running a ctrl + p on an angular page only prints what you see on the screen

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I must configure my web page to print the entire document generated in html, by pressing ctrl + p I can only see what is seen on the screen (similar to a screenshot).

If in the browser I am seeing this on the screen, and I press ctrl + p,
[image]

what the browser will try to print is this: (Only 1 page)
[image]

How do I configure that when I perform a ctrl + p or click on the print option of the browser, it prints the entire html document?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the page size

```
 @media print {
    @page {
      size: landscape;
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
 }
```

Comment: to each of the pages? or to the container of the whole document?

Comment: To the container

Comment: doesnt work with native print function,
clic menu browser options, print, doesnt work.